# Let $X$ be a topological space such that $X \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Must $X$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, low-dimensional-topology, product-space

This question was posted on twitter [here](https://twitter.com/DiracDeltaFunk/status/1621575720488296448) as a quiz but the author never gave an answer, so I thought I'd try here. I don't have much experience with topology so I'm stumped. From searching online it seems that it's not the case in general (e.g. $X \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$  does NOT imply $X \cong \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$) so I figure that the answer will have to use the fact that the product space is two dimensional, or that the quotient (either the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomoprhic to $X$ or the fibers of that map)  are one dimensional. Some people on twitter mentioned trying to prove that $X$ (or the image of $X$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has all the properties that distinguish the real numbers line topologically (i.e. connected, locally connected separable metric space, such that every point is a strong cut point). Perhaps once can also impose an ordering on $X$ that matches the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$?

I'm pretty sure that the map $ \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow X $ induced by the product is a quotient map, perhaps this preserves useful properties such as being connected, locally connected, etc.? Also $X$ seems to be a sub-metric space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by embedding every point $x \in X$ into $\phi(x, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $\phi$ is the isomorphism from $X \times \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products) might help.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the link. Unfortunately most of the answers provide examples of _different_ spaces where this is or is not the case (e.g. if X is a torus with two holes, or some sort of n-sphere, etc.) Unless I'm missing something, none of the answers cover the case where X x R =~ R^2

Comment: Update: After digging through the links one of the mathoverflow answers, I found this paper which might be relevant: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm33/fm33129.pdf ("It is the purpose of this paper.... to show that a decomposition of any n-dimensional manifold into a product of sets of dimension <= 2 is possible in one manner at most")

Comment: ^ Unfortunately it seems that this paper defines 'manifold'  as a  _compact_ manifold, so it probably doesn't apply to R^2.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer? Are you waiting for a better one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $X$ will be homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$. Indeed, $X\times \{0\}\subset {\mathbb R}^2$, hence, $X$ is metrizable. Since $X$ is a quotient of ${\mathbb R}^2$, it follows that $X$ is separable. For the same reason, it is connected. Furthermore, for every $x\in X$,
$$
L_x=\{x\}\times {\mathbb R}\subset {\mathbb R}^2
$$
is properly embedded, hence, by Jordan Curve Theorem, it separates ${\mathbb R}$ in exactly two path-components. Hence, $\{x\}$ separates $X$ in exactly two path-components.

It, therefore, follows from the 2nd answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319870/homeomorphic-characterization-of-the-real-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $X$ is homeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: +1. Pedantically, you should say that $X\times \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, so $X$ is metrizable and separable.

Comment: Does the Jordan Curve Theorem apply here if the image of $ \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ is not compact (i.e. it looks like the real number line)? Do you use the fact that it's a properly embedded submanifold?

Comment: @Raphael: Properly implies that the map extends to $f: [-\infty, \infty]\to R^2\cup\{\infty\}$ so that $f(\pm\infty)=\infty$. Then your apply JCT to the image of this extension.